# Employing LeakyReLU as the activation function of my CNN model causes 'nan' loss during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

When I change my CNN model's activation from `ReLU` to `LeakyReLU`, both training and validation losses become `nan`. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my model's summary:

```
Shape of all data: (1889, 10801)
Shape of X_train: (1322, 10800, 1)
Shape of Y_train: (1322, 3)
Shape of X_test: (567, 10800, 1)
Shape of y_test: (567, 3)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_48 (Conv1D)           (None, 10721, 128)        10368     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_48 (Batc (None, 10721, 128)        512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_48 (Activation)   (None, 10721, 128)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_41 (MaxPooling (None, 5360, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)         (None, 5360, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_49 (Conv1D)           (None, 5357, 128)         65664     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_49 (Batc (None, 5357, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_49 (Activation)   (None, 5357, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_42 (MaxPooling (None, 2678, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_30 (Dropout)         (None, 2678, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_50 (Conv1D)           (None, 2675, 128)         65664     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_50 (Batc (None, 2675, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_50 (Activation)   (None, 2675, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_43 (MaxPooling (None, 1337, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_31 (Dropout)         (None, 1337, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_51 (Conv1D)           (None, 1334, 256)         131328    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_51 (Batc (None, 1334, 256)         1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_51 (Activation)   (None, 1334, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_44 (MaxPooling (None, 667, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_6 (Glob (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 512)               131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 1539      
=================================================================
```

The model was compiled as follows:

```
n_lr = 1e-5
weight_decay = 1e-4
adam = Adam(lr=n_lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=weight_decay)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])
```

p.s. I'm aware of that this issue has already been reported to *Keras* [on *GitHub*](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6615); but it has not got any responses as of posting this question.

Comment: It is not a solution, but, have you tried using tensorflow.keras instead of keras? I am trying to create a model on my laptop and I am not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks @Oscar for your comment. I have not tried your recommendation before but nothing was changed when I did it.

Comment: Have you tried with the most recent version of tensorflow?

Comment: Did you try implementing LeakyReLU by yourself from scratch? Just to confirm that this issue is related to Keras' LeakyReLU layer.

Comment: @jakub Thanks for your comment. I'm using _Colab_, so I think it'd be the most stable version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Frightera. No, I'm employing the `LeakyReLU` layer provided by _Keras_.

Comment: There is no problem of using 'LeakyRelu' activation function in your model. You can verify in this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/f1f39ca5b50b290aec12eb0f05f82511/leakyrelu.ipynb) which I already replicated. There could be problem with using extra `BatchNormalization` layers or `Dropout` layers in model definition. Please check the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014038/tensorflow-binarycrossentropy-loss-quickly-reaches-nan) for your reference. Please try again and let us know if issue still persists.