# TensorFlow BinaryCrossentropy loss quickly reaches NaN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nan, loss-function

**TL;DR** - **ML model loss, when retrained with new data, reaches NaN quickly. All of the "standard" solutions don't work.**

Hello,

Recently, I (successfully) trained a CNN/dense-layered model to be able to classify spectrograms (image representations of audio.) I wanted to try training this model **again** with new data and made sure that it was the correct dimensions, etc.

However, for some reason, the BinaryCrossentropy loss function steadily declines until around 1.000 and suddenly becomes "NaN" within the first epoch. I have tried lowering the learning rate to 1e-8, am using ReLu throughout and sigmoid for the last layer, but nothing seems to be working. Even simplifying the network to only dense layers, this problem still happens. While I have manually normalized my data, I am pretty confident I did it right so that all of my data falls between [0, 1]. There might be a hole here, but I think that is unlikely.

I attached my code for the model architecture here:

```
input_shape = (125, 128, 1)

model = models.Sequential([
    
    layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape=input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),

    layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    
    layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    
    layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    
    layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    
    layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
])
```

Interestingly though, I tried using this new data to fine-tune a VGG16 model, and it worked! (there is no loss NaN problem.) I've attached that code here, but I genuinely have no idea where/if there is any difference causing the problem:

```
base_model = keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet", 
    input_shape=(125, 128, 3),
    include_top=False,
) 

# Freeze the base_model
base_model.trainable = False

# Create new model on top
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(125, 128, 3))
x = inputs
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()
```

I think I've been through all of the "book" solutions, and still can't seem to find the source of the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I am pretty confident I did it right" is not sufficient. If you are using log-magnitude spectrograms you might have some `log(0)` cases in your data which will break your model. You have to check for this explicitly. Also note that the VGG version is completely different as you are training it on 3-channel images, i.e. you are likely interpreting the spectrograms as RGB images, whereas your own model works on the magnitudes directly. You cannot compare the two.

Comment: What's the loss function you pass to your model when calling `model.compile` ?

Comment: @xdurch0 I am using TensorFlow IO’s built-in spectrogram, mel-spectorgram, and dB-mel-spectrogram functions, so I don’t think `log(0)` cases are the issue.

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc I am using `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with some of my input data (divide by zero error during normalization.) Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `kernel_regularizers`, `BatchNormalization` and `dropout` layer from `Convolution layers` which are not required. 
Keep `kernel_regularizers` and `Dropout` only in `Dense` layers in your model definition as well as change the `number of kernels` in Conv2d layer.

and try again training your model using below code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_h,img_w,3)),
    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),

    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    
    Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    
    Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    
    Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu'),#, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
    #BatchNormalization(),
    
    #Dropout(0.3),
    
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(...
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
63/63 [==============================] - 9s 97ms/step - loss: 1.0032 - accuracy: 0.5035 - val_loss: 0.8219 - val_accuracy: 0.6160
Epoch 2/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 88ms/step - loss: 0.7575 - accuracy: 0.5755 - val_loss: 0.7256 - val_accuracy: 0.6120
Epoch 3/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 88ms/step - loss: 0.7181 - accuracy: 0.5805 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.6360
Epoch 4/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 88ms/step - loss: 0.6749 - accuracy: 0.6190 - val_loss: 0.6671 - val_accuracy: 0.6300
Epoch 5/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 95ms/step - loss: 0.6571 - accuracy: 0.6500 - val_loss: 0.6850 - val_accuracy: 0.5980
Epoch 6/20
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 80ms/step - loss: 0.6319 - accuracy: 0.6720 - val_loss: 0.6243 - val_accuracy: 0.6730
Epoch 7/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 90ms/step - loss: 0.5923 - accuracy: 0.6935 - val_loss: 0.6144 - val_accuracy: 0.7120
Epoch 8/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 89ms/step - loss: 0.5643 - accuracy: 0.7205 - val_loss: 0.6136 - val_accuracy: 0.6700
Epoch 9/20
63/63 [==============================] - 6s 93ms/step - loss: 0.5552 - accuracy: 0.7380 - val_loss: 0.5669 - val_accuracy: 0.7080
Epoch 10/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 58ms/step - loss: 0.5423 - accuracy: 0.7400 - val_loss: 0.5819 - val_accuracy: 0.7120
Epoch 11/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 57ms/step - loss: 0.4905 - accuracy: 0.7745 - val_loss: 0.6146 - val_accuracy: 0.7020
Epoch 12/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 57ms/step - loss: 0.4808 - accuracy: 0.7900 - val_loss: 0.6318 - val_accuracy: 0.7070
Epoch 13/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 60ms/step - loss: 0.4602 - accuracy: 0.7990 - val_loss: 0.5707 - val_accuracy: 0.7160
Epoch 14/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 61ms/step - loss: 0.4291 - accuracy: 0.8190 - val_loss: 0.6392 - val_accuracy: 0.6910
Epoch 15/20
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 69ms/step - loss: 0.4003 - accuracy: 0.8355 - val_loss: 0.7048 - val_accuracy: 0.7110
Epoch 16/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 58ms/step - loss: 0.3658 - accuracy: 0.8430 - val_loss: 0.8027 - val_accuracy: 0.7180
Epoch 17/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 58ms/step - loss: 0.3069 - accuracy: 0.8750 - val_loss: 0.9428 - val_accuracy: 0.6970
Epoch 18/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 59ms/step - loss: 0.2601 - accuracy: 0.9005 - val_loss: 0.9420 - val_accuracy: 0.7170
Epoch 19/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 60ms/step - loss: 0.2061 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.9134 - val_accuracy: 0.7290
Epoch 20/20
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 62ms/step - loss: 0.1770 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 1.0805 - val_accuracy: 0.6930
```